# Send Email PHP script cannot receive

Tags: php, email, send

help!

i want to send email with php
this is the script

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
{
//send email
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$subject = $_POST['subject'] ;
$message = $_POST['message'] ;
mail("faimaknyus@gmail.com", $subject,
$message, "From:" . $email);
echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
}
else
//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
{
echo "<form method='post' action='email.php'>
Email: <input name='email' type='text'><br>
Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
Message:<br>
<textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
</textarea><br>
<input type='submit'>
</form>";
}
?>
```

when i send im not receive that message link to my experiment --> http://goo.gl/2bDcLL

Comment: no error messages?  please include in your post whether you received an error message or not and what the error was if you received one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't this PHP mail script work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15695953/why-wont-this-php-mail-script-work)

Comment: now its work. just need restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working. have tested it. Make sure your website SMTP configuration setting are set correctly. For that you can contact your hosting provider.